# PHP error about statement, verified the query and variables

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$stmt8 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE centralizator_alerte 
                SET nr_alerte_nevalidate= nr_alerte_nevalidate-1,
                    nr_alerte_confirmate= nr_alerte_confirmate+1, 
                    timp_total_raportare_catalogare = timp_total_raportare_catalogare+?,
                    timp_mediu_raportare_catalogare=timp_total_raportare_catalogare/(nr_alerte_confirmate+nr_alerte_incorect_raportate+nr_alerte_gresit_raportate) 
                WHERE id_problema = ?");
$stmt8->bind_param("ss", $timp_raportare_catalogare, $id_problema);
$stmt8->execute();
```

Checking the `error_log` shows me that

> [14-May-2020 14:23:58 Europe/Bucharest] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in .... on line 162

Line 162 it's the `bind_param` that I added above. Having this `error` made me believe that the `prepare` returned `false`, so I copy-pasted the entire query in my `SQL database` and ran it, using values instead of `?`, and it worked, the `update` updated my table. So, the next step was about the variables that I use in bind_param, so I checked them right before the `$stmt` and `echo-ing` them showed me that the values are alright indeed. I ran out of things to check, so I would like to ask if someone sees anything else?

Comment: have you a) put the variables themselves in the SELECT statement (in the app, not SQL database), and b) put the variables in the SELECT statement in place of the ?.

Comment: i have tried both ways, if I the variables direct in the `SELECT` statement it's gives me the same error, but for `execut()`

Comment: You could simply check the content of `$stmt8` if you dont believe the error. do a `var_dump($stmt8)` and see what comes out

Comment: it is false, but I cannot see why it would be.

Comment: Changing every value with a given one, it works in my `phpmyadmin` `sql` interface, but the `vardump` still outputs `false`

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Thanks you so much @RiggsFolly! That really helps! I managed to find the issue from the question above, but your info would certainly help me over time!